# Spring Boot http request long poll

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want meet the following use case in Spring Boot.

1. I have a third party REST API, which returns a response asap if there is anything to return or take 10 seconds to send blank response.
2. I need to invoke this API continuously means if API returns response send that response to process and again invoke that API
   means I need to long poll that API but there is no time interval as soon as I get response go to poll again.
3. I want to independent thread for processing response.
4. This is not a web application. I want to implement it only with pure java (spring) and not with java script or JQuery.

How I can implement this in Spring Boot. I read regarding comet and atmosphere while googling but there is no specific information
or sample code regarding third party HTTP request polling or may be I am missing something.

May be I am looking a solution like kafka consumer client.

**Update**

I have tried this with Java Timer as below, can you suggest if there is any other better way.

```
public void pollMsg(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::sendMsg).thenAccept(this::notify);
        }

        private <String> java.lang.String sendMsg() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            java.lang.String msg  = restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com", java.lang.String.class);
            return msg;
        }

        private <String> void notify(java.lang.String msg) {
            System.out.println("Process this message for further: " + msg);
            run();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 2000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So why cant you run a background thread that will do exactly what you want in a loop?

1. Send API request
2. Get response - from your description it can be something or empty response after 10 sec
3. Process that response
4. Go to 1.

Comment: I have updated question with solution, can you please let me know if there is any better solution  for this.

Comment: Looks fine to me